# Custom linux kernel does not boot

Tags: kernel, boot, beagleboneblack

I have prepared a  uboot.img, MLO, uImage, am335x-boneblack.dtb, uEnv.txt Files for Beaglebone black board by following from this site

http://embedjournal.com/kernel-compilation-beaglebone-black

I also created boot and rfs partition on sd card and copied MLO then uboot.img and then other files. I booted by holding switch S2 and got this log

```
U-Boot SPL 2016.07-00224-g62a3b7d (Jul 16 2016 - 23:35:47)
Trying to boot from MMC1
MMC partition switch failed
*** Warning - MMC partition switch failed, using default environment

reading u-boot.img
reading u-boot.img


    U-Boot 2016.07-00224-g62a3b7d (Jul 16 2016 - 23:35:47 +0530)

    I2C:   ready
    DRAM:  512 MiB
    MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
    *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

    Net:   <ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
    cpsw, usb_ether
    Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 2 seconds
    switch to partitions #0, OK
    mmc0 is current device
    SD/MMC found on device 0
    reading boot.scr
    ** Unable to read file boot.scr **
    reading uEnv.txt
    351 bytes read in 4 ms (85 KiB/s)
    Loaded env from uEnv.txt
    Importing environment from mmc0 ...
    Running uenvcmd ...
    Booting from Network ...
    reading uImage
    7677504 bytes read in 690 ms (10.6 MiB/s)
    reading am335x-boneblack.dtb
    61606 bytes read in 13 ms (4.5 MiB/s)
    ## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 82000000 ...
       Image Name:   Linux-4.4.15+
       Created:      2016-07-16  18:30:19 UTC
       Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
       Data Size:    7677440 Bytes = 7.3 MiB
       Load Address: 80008000
       Entry Point:  80008000
       Verifying Checksum ... OK
    ## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
       Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
       Loading Kernel Image ... OK
       Loading Device Tree to 8ffed000, end 8ffff0a5 ... OK

    Starting kernel ...
```

It just cannot boot kernel I don't know why?

Comment: Pointer, do you have any working kernel and dts (logs of build if from linaro or any other distribution, config file, compiler and flags used; *what was your "make" command for kernel*)? Can you compare config/options/logs? Do you have hardware debugger for the board (jtag, arm debug, coresight... - http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardOpenOCD)? Is your *revision of board* same as used by post's author?

Comment: How I can know if the kernel works? I will post logs once I will do all of this once again. I do not have any debugger with me.

Comment: pointer accurate, can you download ready-to-use, compiled kernel? (prebuilt images http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#Method_1:_Download_a_Complete_Pre-Configured_Image). It should boot and work (do some ethernet is there is, possibly blink leds...). If serial console of kernel was enabled, it may write useful info to the serial port (how did you get log?). Do  check revisions and dts of your revision: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack#Board_Revisions_and_Changes

Comment: I have a serial terminal that shows boot time logs. BBB have a emmc that contains a prebuilt setup of kernel and boot file. What I am trying is to compile own boot files in kernel and boot.Right  now I am taking same kernel as you told.